# Is possible save 3 or more canvas.toDataURL() in one value?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want save canvas in every 2 minutes.

```
document.getElementById('canvasUrl').value = canvas.toDataURL();
```

I try:

```
document.getElementById('canvasUrl').value += canvas.toDataURL();
//or
var canvasValue += canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('canvasUrl').value = canvasValue;
```

both can't work! Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can but you need to combine the image data first prior to using a `dataURL` here is an example. Please note it's very verbose I imagine you'd want multiple canvases in an array or something along those lines.

How this works is it takes the data from the first 3 canvases then draws them to the 4th, the 4th canvases dataURL is what's used which has the data from the previous 3 canvases combined.

```js
const canvas1 = document.querySelector('#first');
const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

const canvas2 = document.querySelector('#second');
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

const canvas3 = document.querySelector('#third');
const ctx3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');


ctx1.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

ctx2.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx2.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);

ctx3.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx3.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 10);

const saveCanvas = document.querySelector('#saved');
const ctxSave = saveCanvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw each of our other canvases onto the canvas we're going to save from.
ctxSave.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0);
ctxSave.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);
ctxSave.drawImage(canvas3, 0, 0);

document.getElementById('canvasUrl').value = saveCanvas.toDataURL();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Saved Canvas Data</label>
  <input id="canvasUrl" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="first"></canvas>
  <canvas id="second"></canvas>
  <canvas id="third"></canvas>
  <canvas id="saved"></canvas>
</div>
```